# Looping the layout that was set up in Interface Builder

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, layout

I just need for someone to point me in the right direction of how I should be doing things. I wanted to make an iOS news like app that would have interface resembling Windows Phone. Large and small image tiles that represent one news item each. Now I was thinking to create some basic layout in storyboard, that would consist out of, for example, a title, and a 3 different sized tiles/images (the gray part on the attached image). Now, I would be getting the data as a JSON array that has holds different news categories so I was wondering if somehow the set up layout could be reused in a for loop since the layout will only repeat itself (the red part on the attached image) and oly the data would be different.[image: repeating layout]

Can this be done, should I even try doing something like this, or should I try to create an entire layout programmatically? I wouldn't mind doing it programatically, it's just that I don't have much experience in creating layouts that way, and wanted to make sure that I don't do something that I might regret later. Thank you for any help and advice.

Comment: If you deploy to iOS6++ only have a look a [UICollectionView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionView_class/Reference/Reference.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible, Create three different classes subclassing UIView to hold three different tiles and then based on news category, you can add one of the subclassed UIView.

```
if(category == NORMALSIZE) {
    TileView1 *tileView = (TileView1 *)[[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TileView1" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
    [self.view addSubview:tileView];
}
else if(category == MEDIUMSIZE) {
    TileView2 *tileView = (TileView2 *)[[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TileView2" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
    [self.view addSubview:tileView];
}
else {
    TileView3 *tileView = (TileView3 *)[[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TileView3" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
    [self.view addSubview:tileView];
}
```